# the current activity only read the nfc card detected

Tags: android, nfc, open-nfc

i am creating an application which contains 2 activity. my application read the nfc tags and perform some web service calls. i need both activity can read  the nfc cards. i set in intent filter of both acitivty.. but the choice dialog box will open. so i need my current activity wil read the NFC card when we touch the card to the reader. can you suggest any design methods...

this is my manifest

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Jwrs">
        <activity
            android:name="MainActivity"
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".HomeFragmentActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use foreground mode. See [my test app](https://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/source/browse/#git/ndeftools-boilerplate) [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ndeftools.boilerplate).

Comment: hi... frnd... how can i use it... is it a jar??

Comment: There is a link to the source there. See the downloads section.

Comment: ya frnd, i download all from the given link in the download section. i need a small description about how this working/logic what u applied.
it will be very helpful if u provide it..

Comment: can we use this method in fragment.??